# Store open days and times

Tags: c#, beginner, datetime, constructor

Currently I'm developing my business entities. I feel that the structure is a tad cumbersome.

What I mean is that a store on a particular day can have different open and closing times. So it's not as simple as a store opens and closes at 09:00 and 17:00 respectively every day at the week. A store may open at 09:00 and 19:00 on only Thursdays etc.

**Entities**

```
public class Store
{
    public int StoreID { get; set;}
    public string StoreName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DayOfWeek> DaysOpen { get; set; }
    public List<KeyValuePair<DayOfWeek, StoreTimes>> DaysAndTimes { get; set; }

}

public class StoreTimes
{
    public string StartTime { get; set;}
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

The initialisation is a but cumbersome, see below.

**Initialisation**

```
 Store store = new Store()
            {
                StoreID = 1,
                StoreName = "Some Store",
                DaysOpen = new List<DayOfWeek>() { DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Tuesday, DayOfWeek.Wednesday },
                DaysAndTimes = new List<KeyValuePair<DayOfWeek, StoreTimes>>()
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<DayOfWeek, StoreTimes>(DayOfWeek.Monday, new StoreTimes()
                    {
                        StartTime = "0900", EndTime = "1700"
                    }),
                    new KeyValuePair<DayOfWeek, StoreTimes>(DayOfWeek.Tuesday, new StoreTimes()
                    {
                        StartTime = "1000", EndTime = "1900"
                    })
                }

            };
```

Yes the initialisation needn't be a problem since the BLL will deal with it but how can this be refactored?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> how can this be refactored?

Improved application of **S**ingle **R**esponsibility **P**rinciple, encapsulation, and domain modeling.

**Start With Good Data Structures**

```
public class StoreTimes {
    public DayOfWeek Day {get; set;}
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

- It is clear that an "hours of operation" must consist of a day along with open and close times.
- So make a proper structure (class) that expresses this concept.
- A complete data structure tends to be very flexible. In our case it will solve the problem @mjolka pointed out.
- It simplifies the hell out of client code. i.e. dealing with "a list of key-value-pairs of days and store-times"

---

**Ensure Objects Are Constructed Correctly**

- Constructor parameters forces the client (code) to supply the required things.
- Arguments (the values passed via parameters) are easily validated up front before attempting to use bad or incomplete data.

.

```
public StoreTimes(DayOfWeek theDay, string startTime, string endTime)
    {
        Day = theDay;
        StartTime = startTime ?? "0000";
        EndTime = endTime ?? "0000";
    }
```

---

**Don't allow Client to Arbitrarily Change State**

- non-public setters.

.

```
public class StoreTimes { 
    public DayOfWeek Day {get; protected set;}
    public string StartTime { get; protected set; }
    public string EndTime { get; protected set; }
```

---

**Use Domain Language**

Stores open and close, they do not start and stop.

```
public class StoreTimes {

    public DayOfWeek Day {get; protected set;}
    public string OpenTime { get; protected set; }
    public string CloseTime { get; protected set; }
}
```

---

**Make Cohesive Classes**

OO programming is an exercise in self-reliance, for the classes. A class should *know* how to do things that is should be doing itself. The client should only have to *tell* to do it.

- At a restaurant you tell them to cook food, you don't do it for them.
- You ask to see a menu, you don't write a menu for them.

.

```
public class StoreTimes {
    public string HoursOfOperation()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} : {1} to {2}", Day, OpenTime, CloseTime);
    }
}
```

---

**New Class Applying All the Points Above**

```
public class HoursOfOperation
{
    protected List<StoreTimes> TheHours { get; set; }

    public HoursOfOperation()
    {
        TheHours = new List<StoreTimes>();
    }

    public void Add(StoreTimes newOpsHours)
    {
        if (newOpsHours == null) return;

        TheHours.Add(newOpsHours);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder me = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (StoreTimes openTime in TheHours)
            me.AppendLine(openTime.HoursOfOperation());

        return me.ToString();
    }
}
```

---

**Lessons Learned Applied to Store Class**

```
public class Store
{
    protected int StoreID { get; set; }
    protected string StoreName { get; set; }
    protected HoursOfOperation OperatingHours { get; set; }

    public Store(string storeName, HoursOfOperation operatingHours, int storeID ){
        StoreID = storeID;
        StoreName = storeName ?? "NoNameStore";

        if (operatingHours == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Operating Hours is null");

        OperatingHours = operatingHours;
    }

    public string HoursOfOperation()
    {
        return this.OperatingHours.ToString();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder me = new StringBuilder();
        me.AppendLine(string.Format("Store {0}  ID {1}", StoreName, StoreID ));
        me.AppendLine("Hours Of Operation:");
        me.AppendLine(HoursOfOperation());

        return me.ToString();
    }
}
```

### Client Code

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HoursOfOperation opsHours = new HoursOfOperation();
        opsHours.Add(new StoreTimes(DayOfWeek.Monday, "0900", "1130"));
        opsHours.Add(new StoreTimes(DayOfWeek.Monday, "1300", "1800"));
        opsHours.Add(new StoreTimes(DayOfWeek.Saturday, "0800", "2100"));
        opsHours.Add(new StoreTimes(DayOfWeek.Sunday, null, null));

        Store CostingTons = new Store("CostingTons", opsHours, 1);
        Console.WriteLine(CostingTons.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
  }
```

Comment: thank you so much for this. Your points make sense. This seems like it will allow for for varying operation hours from week to week. So if a store is closing early for a week, yes I'll modify the structure to support this, but this will get me onto the right track.

Comment: Me: "Hey! Look at that great answer! Oh... It's @radarbob... *of course it's a great answer*."

Answer (score 2):

You're interested in a `Dictionary<DayOfWeek, StoreTimes>()` which, coincidentally, actually inherits from `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.

Additionally I would also suggest adding a `StoreTimes(string start, string end)` constructor so you can initialize properly (and it should be a requirement either way).

This would result in code like this:

```
DaysAndTimes = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, StoreTimes>()
{
    { DayOfWeek.Monday, new StoreTimes("1300", "1700") },
    { DayOfWeek.Tuesday, new StoreTimes("0900", "1700") }
}
```

Additionally, I would suggest turning your `DaysOpen` into a `HashSet` or an array so you don't have to deal with an O(n) lookup. Or you omit it altogether and just combine the usage with your dictionary: only add the days you're open in `DaysAndTimes` and try to retrieve the day from there.

Comment: A `Dictionary<DayOfWeek, StoreTimes>` might be too limiting, as it won't allow for opening hours such as Monday 9:30 am – 2:00 pm, 4:00 – 8:00 pm. Opening hours like these are very common in Spain, at least.

Comment: @mjolka: that's something that should be solved in `StoreTimes` though, I would still stay with the dictionary to relate a day to (a certain set of) openinghours.